# how can I get value of "__type" key in a json with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Solution:

I found the problem, that is stylus parser rewrite the function toJSON, so although the ast print like following, but actually ast object don't have __type property, so it causes the problem.

---

Question:

I am using stylus ast tree which is like :

```
{
"__type": "Root",
"nodes": [
  {
    "__type": "Ident",
    "name": "some-mixin",
    "val": {
      "__type": "Function",
      "name": "some-mixin",
      "lineno": 1,
      "column": 16,
      "params": {
        "__type": "Params",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "__type": "Ident",
            "name": "a",
            "val": {
              "__type": "Null"
            },
            "mixin": false,
            "lineno": 1,
            "column": 12
          },
          ...
```

it's a tree expressed by json.

and I want to get value of "__type", but using ["__type"] to get the value, undefined is returned.

it seems like "__type" has some special meaning in json, how can I get the value of "__type"?

PS:
I tried `object.__type` to get the value, it doesn't work.

In addition, I found some weird thing

```
typeof ast // returns object
```

I use JSON.stringify(ast), and __type is in the string
But I use console.log(ast), __type is missing, I don't know why..

And also I tried

```
console.log(ast.hasOwnProperty('__type')) //return false
```

PPS: I run this code in node v0.12.0

Thanks for your help!

Comment: this looks more like a javascript object with private properties, have you tried the dot notation `object.__type`?

Comment: Seems fine: https://jsfiddle.net/sypx3tom/

Comment: `__type` doesn't have a special meaning or restrictions. You can access it like any other property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"__type" is not specially recognized in any way by JavaScript. Verify that the AST has been parsed to an object. If it is still a JSON string, you'll get `undefined`. You can be absolutely sure by using the `typeof` operator on your AST. It should return "object" rather than "string". If its "string" then you have to use `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 0):

you could try dot notation:

```
var x = {"__type": "Ident"};

console.log(x['__type']); // with 'string'
console.log(x.__type); // with 'dot'
```

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing special about "__type" in JS. I would defiantly test the typeof to insure that you are dealing with an object. Does your JSON object have a name? You can also try this to test the first object.

```
nameOfYourObject['__type']

// if there are more than one
nameOfYourObject[0]['__type']
```

or if you are reaching into the object:

```
nameOfYourObject.nodes[0]['__type']

// if there are more than one
nameOfYourObject[0].nodes[0]['__type']
```